# how can i import my own code style xml files in clion ?

Tags: c++, clion

I have my own code style in clion but i couldn't find xml files setting window.

here is picture about that.[image]

They said there will be xml files config/codestyles under my home directory, however i cannot find config/codestyles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to navigate through the settings like follows: File / Settings… / Editor / Code Style / C/C++ / Manage… / Import… / Intellij IDEA code style XML / Select Path (to .xml file)